# How to clear the contents of a canvas in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, zooming

How to clear the contents of a canvas in wpf? Tried canvas.clear() doesn't work.
Also how can i add zoom control in a wpf application? Zoom with a scroller to move the image.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to do `MyCanvas.Children.Clear();`

Tested with the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" Content="Clear"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyCanvas.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "Foo" });
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCanvas.Children.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Also, could you please help me out with zooming? I'm creating an application in which the user uploads a map and draws on it. Without zoom, I'm able to draw the map but with zoomslider control i'm not able to draw. I have been breaking my head over zoom control, any ideas would be great. Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work for me.